# Play Framework 2.1 Password Encryption

Tags: database, encryption, playframework, cryptography, passwords

I have an application that talks to the database for which I have to load the credentials for the database connection from my `application.conf`. I would like to have my credentials, at least the password encrypted in the `application.conf` file. I was not able to find some good documentation on how this fits together with Play.

I mean I can use any encryption library, encrypt the password, store it to the `application.conf` and decrypt when I connect to the database. What I want to know is some suggestions on how this fits with Play framework. Is there some built-in plugin or something that I can use for encryption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to encrypt anything inside your own system. Just make sure your server is secure.

Since you will need to let your application access the password, an attacker who has access to your system would be able to get to your password anyway.

But **never ever** check your passwords into git (or subversion or whatever)!

*Instead what you should do is this:*

1. Add this line to your `application.conf`:

   ```
   include "secret.conf"
   ```
2. Create the `secret.conf` in your `conf`-folder and save all your credentials in this file.
3. Add `secret.conf` to your `.gitignore`, so it doesn't go into your Git.
4. Manually add and update the `secret.conf`-file on your server.

If you are on a Linux-system it's also smart to control read access to the `secret.conf`-file like @Roman said:

> Make sure only the user running play has rights to read that file.

Comment: You can also use something like [keywhiz](https://square.github.io/keywhiz/) to manage secrets. If you're using Docker swarm, you can use the built in [secret management](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/), or if you use AWS they have [KeyManagement](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/). You can find some more key management solutions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_management)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it would be useless to encrypt your db credentials. That way you must store somewhere a key to decrypt the credentials, which leads to exactly the same problem.
Instead you could store an `application-prod.conf` on your production server where you can overwrite `application.conf` properties. Make sure only the user running play has rights to read that file.

```
include "application"

db.default.password="yoursecret"
```

Then run your application:

```
/path/to/yourapp/bin/yourapp -Dconfig.file=/path/to/application-prod.conf
```

The same approach is used to protect the application secret. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ApplicationSecret and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/Configuration.

Comment: Good point about the read access!

Comment: According to Play document, we have other options to override the config:  

* with JVM options when running Play: -Ddb.default.password=secret  
* with environment variables in application.conf: db.default.password=${?DB_SECRET}

Comment: Or we can use onLoadConfig() in GlobalSettings to modify the configuration once loaded (e.g decrypt the password).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088411/how-to-change-play-2-framework-db-configuration-at-runtime