# How to change configuration in play dynamically via JMX

Tags: scala, playframework, jmx, mbeans

I have my configuration for my Scala Play application in my application.conf file.

For now, everytime I want to change the configuration I have to make a deployment.

Can anybody help me finding out, how to expose the Configuration as a MBean?
I would like to change the configuration without deployment.

Didn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: could be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088411/how-to-change-play-2-framework-db-configuration-at-runtime

Comment: This look not very handy. With JMX, I could see the current configuration
and change the current configuration more easy.

Comment: It never too easy, configuration already loaded into application. For ex. DB connection already setup. Even if you change Configuration object it does not necessary means your services use latest configs.

Comment: @rumoku that's right, but still would be good to be able to restart instead of redeploy :)
Will track this question, probably community will have a solution.

Comment: @Alexander Arendar for yourscenario check the link I've added above. It's recommended to override `onLoadConfig` method of `GlobalSetting` trait, where you can use different data source for your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Redeploy just for a configuration change is really boring and I understand you want to avoid that.

Changing configuration while the application is running is a risky operation and I would not recommend going in that direction.
But there are a few techniques that the framework provides that would only require a restart of the application.

Play allows you to point to an external file with your configuration

```
$ your-app -Dconfig.file=/full/path/to/conf/application-prod.conf
```

Besides that in your conf file you can use environment variables, so you can configure different servers differently using the same application.conf

```
my.key = defaultvalue
my.key = ${?MY_KEY_ENV}
```

And run your app using

```
$ your-app -DMY_KEY_ENV=bar
```

Reference:

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production
- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration